# How to convert table columns to desired types all at once?

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I have this csv file that is read to a `table` variable using `readtable`. So, all columns are of type `cell` containing string values. The actual data is of types `double`, `int32`, `datetime`, `logical`, and `string`. I'm converting them column by column. I want to convert specific columns that are of same type, or maybe convert all columns at once. Is that possible?

Here's a sample of what I'm doing now, but my table has 63 columns:

```
clear variables;
%% simulate readtable
C = {...
'34145823','2015-12-08 00:15:55','3.2','1';
'34157170','2015-12-08 13:29:30','0.5','0';
'34157958','2015-12-08 14:07:00','-1.7','1'};
T = table(C(:, 1), C(:, 2), C(:, 3), C(:, 4), ...
    'variablenames', {'int32Col', 'datetimeCol', 'doubleCol', 'logicalCol'});
varfun(@class, T, 'OutputFormat', 'cell')
%% type conversion
T.int32Col = int32(str2double(T.int32Col));
T.datetimeCol = datetime(T.datetimeCol);
T.doubleCol = str2double(T.doubleCol);
T.logicalCol = cell2mat(T.logicalCol) == '1';
varfun(@class, T, 'OutputFormat', 'cell')
T
```

**P.S.:** all values in these csv files are enclosed between `"`s, and that's why they are read as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to at least specify the datatype of each column, but once you've done that a switch statement will let you loop through the columns without having to go through one by one.

I introduced `varNames` as the name of each column---I presume you can get this from your csv file. I also introduced `varTypes` which is the datatype of each column, I think you'll have to make this by hand, maybe you can automate it depending on your actual csv files.

```
clear variables;
% simulate readtable
C = {...
    '34145823','2015-12-08 00:15:55','3.2','1';
    '34157170','2015-12-08 13:29:30','0.5','0';
    '34157958','2015-12-08 14:07:00','-1.7','1'};
varNames = {'int32Col', 'datetimeCol', 'doubleCol', 'logicalCol'};
T = table(C(:, 1), C(:, 2), C(:, 3), C(:, 4), ...
    'variablenames', varNames);

varTypes = {'int32' 'date' 'double' 'logical'};
for i = 1:size(T,2)
    switch varTypes{i}
        case 'int32'
            T.(varNames{i}) = int32(str2double(T{:,i}));
        case 'date'
            T.(varNames{i}) = datetime(T{:,i});
        case 'double'
            T.(varNames{i}) = str2double(T{:,i});
        case 'logical'
            T.(varNames{i}) = logical(cell2mat(T{:,i}));
    end
end
```